# Change Worklight Application status on Console using action file

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I need to know if I can change the status of the application on Worklight Console using action file that I can run on the server.

Details:

In our production server, we need to change the status of the previous versions of the application from "Active" to "Active, Notifying" then to "Access Disabled".
This can be achieved from the WL console and we can write the notification message that will be sent to the user:

[image]

However, to avoid the "human" work on our Prod environment, we are looking to use an action file to be run on the server which will do the change.

Is this possible. Or this should be from the Console?

WL Version : 6.2.0.1

PS: We use an action file to change any property on our WebSphere server.

Action File example (Looking for something similar):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
    Environment specific WebSphere configuration management XML file.

    Warning: This file contains clear text passwords and, therefore, cannot be
             distributed outside of the eCommerce group without masking the
             password values.
-->
<!DOCTYPE WAS [
  <!-- Environment specific parameters -->

  <!ENTITY KEY_STORE_PATH "/was85/resources/security/ecommerce_bk_mobile.p12">
]>
<WAS>
  <!-- Applications: Application Types: WebSphere enterprise applications -->
  <Application
    name="IBM_Worklight_project_runtime_MobileBanking">

    <!-- Enterprise Applications > application_name > Environment entries for Web modules -->

    <WebAppBinding _action="update"
      description="[OPTIONAL] SSL certificate keystore location. Default: conf/default.keystore."
      module="Worklight"
      name="ssl.keystore.path"
      uri="MobileBanking.war,WEB-INF/web.xml"
      value="&KEY_STORE_PATH;"/>
  </Application>
</WAS>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use "action files".

In Worklight, you can use the REST APIs services that allow you to manage... stuff, such as setting Remote Disable.

See here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/apiref/c_restapi_oview.html

And specifically for Remote Disable (info and example): http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/apiref/r_restapi_app_version_access_rule_put.html

Comment: Thank you Idan, I believe in my case i need to use the xml example to accomplish my request, correct!